# How do I get wexpect to interact a python script?

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect, wexpect

Folks, I would like to know if there is an issue w/ wexpect.
Is this module working as expected?

things seem to work as expected in pexpect on linux

```
import wexpect
child = wexpect.spawn('cmd')
child.expect('>')  #instantaneous response
child.sendline('python3')
child.expect('>')  #this stays stuck here for 15 seconds before returning with success (pexpect is instantaneous)
child.sendline('import os')
child.expect('>') #instantaneous response
child.sendline('os.curdir')
child.expect('>') #instantaneous response
child.sendline()
child.expect('>') #raises TIMEOUT
child.before() 
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
#contrast this to pexpect: b">>> os.curdir\r\n'.'\r\n>>> os.curdir\r\n'.'\r\n>>> "
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could just use pexpect directly:
[pexpect windows support starting version 4.0](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#pexpect-on-windows)

```
import pexpect
from pexpect.popen_spawn import PopenSpawn
child = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn('cmd')
child.sendline('py -3 -i')
child.expect('>{2,}')
child.before #gives the string before the match
child.after #gives the match string
```